# Spark Dataframe returns NULL for entire row when one column value of that row is NULL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Input data -

```
{"driverId":1,"driverRef":"hamilton","number":44,"code":"HAM","name":{"forename":"Lewis","surname":"Hamilton"},"dob":"1985-01-07","nationality":"British","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Hamilton"}
{"driverId":2,"driverRef":"heidfeld","number":"\\N","code":"HEI","name":{"forename":"Nick","surname":"Heidfeld"},"dob":"1977-05-10","nationality":"German","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Heidfeld"}
{"driverId":3,"driverRef":"rosberg","number":6,"code":"ROS","name":{"forename":"Nico","surname":"Rosberg"},"dob":"1985-06-27","nationality":"German","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nico_Rosberg"}
{"driverId":4,"driverRef":"alonso","number":14,"code":"ALO","name":{"forename":"Fernando","surname":"Alonso"},"dob":"1981-07-29","nationality":"Spanish","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Alonso"}
{"driverId":5,"driverRef":"kovalainen","number":"\\N","code":"KOV","name":{"forename":"Heikki","surname":"Kovalainen"},"dob":"1981-10-19","nationality":"Finnish","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heikki_Kovalainen"}
{"driverId":6,"driverRef":"nakajima","number":"\\N","code":"NAK","name":{"forename":"Kazuki","surname":"Nakajima"},"dob":"1985-01-11","nationality":"Japanese","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuki_Nakajima"}
{"driverId":7,"driverRef":"bourdais","number":"\\N","code":"BOU","name":{"forename":"Sébastien","surname":"Bourdais"},"dob":"1979-02-28","nationality":"French","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9bastien_Bourdais"}
```

After reading this data into spark dataframe while display that df, I could se  entire row for driverId 2,5,6,7 is NULL. I could see column-number value is NULL for that driver id.

Here is my code. Any mistakes here?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DateType

name_field = StructType(fields =[
  StructField("forename", StringType(), True),
  StructField("surname", StringType(), True)
])

driver_schema = StructType(fields =[
  StructField("driverId", IntegerType(), False),
  StructField("driverRef", StringType(), True),
  StructField("number", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("code", StringType(), True),
  StructField("name", name_field),
  StructField("dob", DateType(), True),
  StructField("nationality", StringType(),True),
  StructField("url", StringType(), True)
])
 
driver_df = spark.read\
.schema(driver_schema)\
.json('dbfs:/mnt/databrickslearnf1azure/raw/drivers.json')

driver_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- driverId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- driverRef: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- forename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: date (nullable = true)
 |-- nationality: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)

display(driver_df)
```

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/notes-about-json-schema-handling-in-spark-sql-be1e7f13839d

Comment: you should change the data type of the number column to string in the explicit schema that you are creating because what you are saying as null is not actual null it is some kind of string value and spark cannot parse it as integer so it shows all columns as null. if you want the data type to be integer than you can convert it to integer after you read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your initial schema to be as follows which assume the number to be of type string.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DateType

name_field = StructType(fields =[
  StructField("forename", StringType(), True),
  StructField("surname", StringType(), True)
])

driver_schema = StructType(fields =[
  StructField("driverId", IntegerType(), False),
  StructField("driverRef", StringType(), True),
  StructField("number", StringType(), True),
  StructField("code", StringType(), True),
  StructField("name", name_field),
  StructField("dob", DateType(), True),
  StructField("nationality", StringType(),True),
  StructField("url", StringType(), True)
])
```

then you can read the data from the json file using the same code that you are using as follows:

```
driver_df = spark.read\
.schema(driver_schema)\
.json('dbfs:/mnt/databrickslearnf1azure/raw/drivers.json')

driver_df.printSchema()
```

Once you have read the data then you can apply the logic to convert "\N" to null and then change the data type of the column from string to integer as below :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = driver_df.withColumn("number", when(driver_df.number=="\\N","null").otherwise(driver_df.number))
finaldf = df.withColumn("number",df.number.cast(IntegerType()))
finaldf.printSchema()
```

Now if you do the display or show on the dataframe you can see the output as below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this because, according to the official databricks docs: [Cause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/scala/from-json-null-spark3#:%7E:text=This%20occurs%20because%20Spark%203.0%20and%20above%20cannot%20parse%20JSON%20arrays%20as%20structs.)

> Spark 3.0 and above (Databricks Runtime
> 7.3 LTS and above) cannot parse JSON arrays as structs. You should pass the schema as ArrayType instead of StructType.

Solution: Pass the schema as ArrayType instead of StructType.

```
driver_schema = ArrayType(StructType(fields =[
  StructField("driverId", IntegerType(), False),
  StructField("driverRef", StringType(), True),
  StructField("number", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("code", StringType(), True),
  StructField("name", name_field),
  StructField("dob", DateType(), True),
  StructField("nationality", StringType(),True),
  StructField("url", StringType(), True)
]))
```